# MessageBox showing some dull theme

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, messagebox

I have telerik messagebox,after loading startup form in my windows application messagebox.show() display popup in designer pattern but before that it popup with some dull theme.
All i want to do is to show 
`RadMessageBox.Show(this, "Body", "header", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Info);`   in my Program.cs,where this should be iwindows32window type.Any help would be appreciated

```
static void Main()
    {//messagebox here displays with dull theme
  Application.Run(new Login());   
//messagebox here displays with original theme
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are showing a message box prior setting your application theme, hence the message box does not have the correct theme. If so, you can use the following method, prior showing the text box, to set its theme:

```
RadMessageBox.SetThemeName("yourThemeNameHere");
```

EDIT:
Here is what you can try:

```
  static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form f = new Form1(); //this contains some Telerik WinForms controls
        Telerik.WinControls.RadMessageBox.SetThemeName("TelerikMetro");
        Telerik.WinControls.RadMessageBox.Show("test");

        Application.Run(f);
    }
```

Comment: As i mention in above comment,i had checked for theme name before asking question.

Comment: just change Application.Run(new Login());  with Login lg = new Login();Application.Run(lg); n it works,thanks